# Multiple AND, OR statements

Tags: php, sql

Hello I would like to know if the following code could be extended with another 'AND', 'OR' statement or does it need another 'IF' statement ?

```
if (in_array("juliette_geinformeerd", $opts)){
$where .= " AND juliette_geinformeerd = 1 ";
}
```

I tryed:

```
if (in_array("juliette_geinformeerd", $opts)){
$where .= " AND juliette_geinformeerd = 1 " . "OR juliette_geinformeerd = 2";
}
```

But that doesnt work.

//Update:

So this piece of code works toghether with AJAX. If you click the checkbox it updates the page and filters options. I would like to filter it on multiple statements instead of just 1 (yes or no).

Comment: you need to be a little more specific: What does not work? Errors/Warnings etc? From a first glance, the code could be valid.

Comment: And what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Try $where .= " AND (juliette_geinformeerd = 1 " . "OR juliette_geinformeerd = 2)";

Comment: @Ramesh - If you are answering the question, post it as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: You seem to create a string that is used in (I guess SQL). In that case: why concatenate? Why not just:
if (in_array("juliette_geinformeerd", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND (juliette_geinformeerd = 1 OR juliette_geinformeerd = 2)";
}

Comment: i think you should print your query to check if the if condition allows .. may be your chekbox value not passing on ajax

Comment: or you can give your ajax code for fixing

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (in_array("juliette_geinformeerd", $opts)){
    $where .= " juliette_geinformeerd = 1 " . "OR juliette_geinformeerd = 2";
    }
// if there is a no other conditions in the where if there any condition so try to write like that:

 $where .="('juliette_geinformeerd_else = 1";   
    if (in_array("juliette_geinformeerd", $opts)){
        $where .= "and juliette_geinformeerd = 1) " . "OR juliette_geinformeerd = 2";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$where .= " AND (juliette_geinformeerd = 1 " . "OR juliette_geinformeerd = 2)";`